# Allowing WhatsApp data through specific bundle

Tags: privacy, whatsapp

My mobile network provider recently released a new GPRS bundle, it consist of 50 MB per month **for WhatsApp data only!**

First, how do they identify WhatsApp data, and more important to me, isn't that compromising our privacy?

I know that the data is being encrypted, but the idea of controlling the data freaks me itself.

> I checked on wireshark and I noticed that some data is transfered using ports: 5222, 5223 and 5228. And there are some data on SSL over 443.
>   
>   That's why I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Even with SSL, the network knows what host you are connecting to. So I imagine that they monitor the IP addresses that your data is going to and bucketize the WhatsApp data into a different payment category.

Comment: But wouldn't that affect our privacy? Imagine a MITM attack for example.

Comment: @Emadeddin: No. They only see that there is encrypted traffic going to or coming from the WhatsApp servers. They can also measure how much traffic it is, but they cannot see or modify the content. You could circumvent that by using a VPN, if your provider gives you more data for other services.

Comment: I disagree. Because I tried to use a VPN, but the bundle stopped working. When using a VPN they will be unable to determine whatsapp data, because I'm tunneling all my connections.

Comment: Correct. Using a VPN provides you with privacy from your wireless provider (it leaves you open to privacy invasion from your VPN provider instead) at the cost of not getting the extra savings that they offer for WhatsApp.

Comment: There is no control, just counting. You have run a test that confirms the limitations.

Comment: If so, then I'm satisfied with your answer, you can either post it or close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network provider will see to which servers on which ports your device will connect.  Your WhatsApp client will connect to well-known servers. So your provider will probably put the traffic you make over some WhatsApp servers into another category than any other traffic.

This can be done by passively looking at your traffic. They probably have some netflow data which provides those information.

The only thing you'll reveal to your provider is that you sent *n* Bits of data to WhatsApp. But the provider knows this anyway.

However there is some chance that the provider could try to execute a man-in-the-middle attack. This means it places itself between you and the WhatsApp server (or any other server). However WhatsApp encryption was explicitly designed with that attack in mind. The whitepaper discusses how sessions are set up and there is no way to successfully mount a man-in-the-middle attack. Also it is not possible for your provider to see to whom you are connecting.

So in general your provider will not see more data than it sees now.

Comment: now with the new end-to-end encryption, I'm sure that there is no MITM. thanks for reply